# kozachenko-leonenko entropy estimation

Tags: density-function, entropy, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to implement the entropy estimation based on the closest neighbor from [Kozachenko and Leonenko](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0305641.pdf) but I'm facing a problem I can't solve.

The idea is to work in a new set $\epsilon=${$\epsilon_{1},...\epsilon_{N}$} instead of {$x_{1},...,x_{N}$} where $\epsilon(i)$ is the distance between $x_{i}$ and its closest neighbor.

The formula of its estimator is:

$\hat H(X)=-\psi(1)+\psi(N)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \log(\epsilon(i))$  where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

But if two $x_{i}$ are equal or if $X$ is a constant variable , then one $\epsilon_{i}=0$ and $\hat H(X)=-\infty$.

Those cases are not treated in the article and I don't know how to adapt the formula.
Not counting the null $\epsilon_{i}$ in the sum is not a good idea.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: in [1], 'not counting' idea is used. in [2], the authors added very low-amplitude noise to the data (10^10, with double precision) [1] http://www.cs.tut.fi/~timhome/tim/tim/core/differential_entropy_kl_details.htm [2] A. Kraskov, H. Stögbauer, and P. Grassberger, “Estimating mutual information,” Phys. Rev. E, vol. 69, no. 6, p. 066138, Jun. 2004.

Answer (score 3):

Use the k-th nearest neighbor instead, for k as large as needed to obtain an $\epsilon_i > 0$. To reflect this in the Kozachenko-Leonenko estimator, simply replace $\psi(1)$ with $\psi(k)$. Since it's allowed to vary k from point to point, you could for instance look for the "closest distinct neighbor" each time. (If you find *all* your $x_i$ to be equal, simply set $\hat{H}(X) = 0$.)